# What if the speed of light was not constant?

Tags: science-based, physics, scientific-development, electromagnetism

How would the laws of physics change if the speed of light was not constant and the [Michaelson-Morley experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michelson%E2%80%93Morley_experiment) was instead proven to be true?

Obviously relativity would not be true, but on a small scale, what would the differences be? Would Maxwell's equations hold up properly? Would electricity work as it does now? How would light *work* (if at all)?

Answers should assume that all discoveries before the [Michaelson-Morley experiment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Michelson%E2%80%93Morley_experiment) still hold (or give reasons why they should not; or why they appeared to hold in the past but a non-constant $c$ shows that they will not hold in all situations)

### Assumptions

If needed:

- No maximum speed of light
- Instantaneous transmission of information is possible, but would have to be via gravity or similar.
- Most things that emit light do so at a constant rate which is comparable to $c$
- Newtonian mechanics work properly for ordinary objects (e.g. planets, thrown balls, etc.)
- Luminous Aether is real: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luminiferous_aether

Comment: I'd like a [hard-science] answer but since this question may involve reworking a century of electromagnetism I removed [hard-science] and went with [science-based].

Comment: You can clarify in the question body that you want answers to conform to the relevant sciences are they were known before the work of Einstein et al. Comments are potentially subject to deletion at any time for any reason, and should not be relied upon to remain.

Comment: This feels like it could easily be horribly broad. You might need to narrow down the scope of what you're asking about.

Comment: I agree, this question is far too broad. The implications are universe changing on many different levels.

Comment: OK, I'll reduce the scope of the question to just the Maxwell equations and thier direct implications tonight (probably changing to [hard-science] tag) . Feel free to mark this as on hold until I can change it.

Comment: When you do, it may be good to take a look at some of the other questions on this site in the form of "What if there was a world exactly like this one, except _________ rule was changed."  They usually degenerate into "The universe would be completely and utterly unlike everything you know."  It may help you write this question around the pitfalls that have afflicted others.

Comment: Note that this is an uncommon but still researched area of physics.  We have found no direct evidence / data of this but apparently there are some niggling details which would be consistent with light speed variation over distance or time.

Comment: I've been thinking about this question and I think it'll be difficult to make this narrow enough for SO format without making it uninteresting/purely an exercise in algebra. I'm happy for this to be closed and I'll ask a new question if I find any more specific parts of this I want answered.

Comment: Information about Variable Speed of Light Theories can be obtained at Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_speed_of_light

Comment: nformation about Variable Speed of Light Theories can be obtained at Wikipedia https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_speed_of_light  Plus there are a reasonable number of modern VSL theories, so you don't need to restart your universe prior to the Michaelson-Morley experiment, and you can forget about the luminiferous ether as it's not needed. I recommend following the link to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jo%C3%A3o_Magueijo as there's a paper outlining the changes to physics from VSL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One part of the Michaelson-Morley experiment is not that light travels at variable speed, but that it travels through the luminiferous aether at a fixed speed and that the Earth was moving through the aether and that the aether might have some movement of its own.

If you assume that this is where the differences start, and that light travels at a given speed through the aether, which is stationary relative to the galaxy, then the main problem comes in the changing speed of light in varying directions (if the aether is not stationary relative to the galaxy, then that would farther complicate things and I won't talk about this).

The sun is currently orbiting around the center of the galaxy at a speed of about 220 km/s, and the earth is orbiting the sun at a speed of about 30 km/s. This would cause the speed of light to potentially vary by up to 500 km/s as measured by scientists on Earth. This may seem like a huge number, but the speed of light is almost 300,000 km/s, so the difference is not that big.

500 km/s change is actually less than the error that scientists had had when calculating the speed of light for almost 200 years after it was discovered that light had a finite speed.

Furthermore, relativity could no longer be the case. It requires that light always travel at a constant speed, so this would cause superluminal travel to no longer be that big of a deal. It simply becomes a matter of accelerating yourself enough, and you don't have to worry about your inertial mass increasing, or time dilation, or length contraction.

Also, red-shift and blue-shift are now caused by an object's movement through the luminiferous aether. This would wreak havoc on astronomy as many astronomical observations depend upon it (such as the universe expanding). Christian Doppler relied on light not traveling through a moving medium in his original discovery of the Doppler Effect in 1842 (before the Michaelson-Morley experiment).

The lack of relativity would actually simplify making a GPS system because modern GPS systems have to adjust for relativistic time dilation.

This lack of space-time curvature also would make the inner solar system more stable because space-time curvature caused by relativity and the sun's mass could make Mercury's orbit unstable and cause it to get more eccentric, eventually being flung out of the solar system, colliding with another planet, or falling into the sun in the next few billions of years.

There are probably much more implications, but I don't think there is a way around the two assumptions that I made (light moves at always the same speed relative to the aether, as thought be the luminiferous aether theory and that the aether's wind is very little relative to the movement of our galaxy) without overly complicating things or destroying the entire universe.